# Azure Logic App: Service Bus Trigger Fails withe error ""message": "Error from token exchange....."

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

The service Bus Trigger fails in Azure Logic App with the below error suddenly.It was working earlier.

---

### Error:
"message": "Error from token exchange: The connection (flow-........) is not found. Please create new connection and change your application to use the new connection."

With the same conn. name / display name:

1. Redeployed the API connection. Doesn't help
2. Deleted and Recreated the API connection . Doesn't help.

If a new connection (with a different conn.name/display name) is created, it works. The error disappears.

Any clues/ideas is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If the connection is working for other flows and apps, then the issue is likely to be with the current flow.

As you mentioned that, you redeployed the API connection  and also deleted, recreated the API connection but that too did not help.

However, it is usually far quicker to delete the action and re-create it, or start again and create a new flow if it's a short flow, or to use a new copy of the flow using  **Save As**  than trying to figure out what's gone wrong.